# Dockerfile Python ModuleNotFoundError: Two almost identical Dockerfiles but one finds the Module but the other doesn't

Tags: python, dockerfile, dependencies, minikube, modulenotfounderror

I've got 2 Dockerfiles, one for my client and one for my server:

Client

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash user
USER user

WORKDIR /home/user

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/home/user"
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin"
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/user"

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && rm requirements.txt
RUN pip install sdv

ADD experiment_parameters experiment_parameters
ADD metrics metrics
COPY Dataclasses.py .
COPY Util.py .
COPY Client.py .
COPY SyntheticDataGenerator.py .
COPY Definitions.py Definitions.py

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "Client.py"]
```

Server:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash user
USER user

WORKDIR /home/user

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/home/user"
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin"
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/user"

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && rm requirements.txt
RUN pip install sdv

ADD experiment_parameters experiment_parameters
ADD metrics metrics
COPY Dataclasses.py .
COPY Util.py .
COPY Server.py .
COPY SyntheticDataGenerator.py .

EXPOSE 54080

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "Server.py"]
```

Both client and server exist in the same code base and are both using a Metrics.py file in my metrics folder.

When I try to deploy the client on my minikube cluster everything works fine and it can access the Metrics.py file.
But when I try to deploy the server it throws a ModuleNotFoundError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Server.py", line 10, in <module>
    from metrics.Metrics import Accuracy, CrossEntropyLoss
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'metrics.Metrics'
```

I tried adding PYTHONPATHs but that didn't seem to work. But I'm also not sure if I did it right. I also built both of the images with the `--no-cache` option but the problem persists. I checked the file system in the image with ls as well and it looked fine. In both of the images there is the metrics directory in the same place with all of the files in it.

Does anyone have an idea what the cause of this problem could be and how I can resolve it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. It was a perstistent volume that I mounted into the same directory where the Metrics.py was. It has just overridden the content of that directory which resulted in the modules not being found.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).